# How change shipping method depends on custom checkout field data woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a custom checkout field to my woocommerce checkout page.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'dropdown' );

function dropdown( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['ilce'] = array(
        'label'       => __('İlçe', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => _x('İlçe', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'    => true,
        'class'       => array(
            'form-row-wide',
            'update_totals_on_change'
        ),
        'clear'       => true,
        'id'          => 'ilcepicker',
        'type'        => 'select',
        'options'     => array(
            'Ataşehir' => __('Ataşehir', 'woocommerce' ),
            'Şişli'    => __('Şişli', 'woocommerce' )
        )//end of options
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

I want to change shipping method according to options that is selected from my custom field. How can i achieve it? I could not find a way.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but could give some pointers you could try. Look for the selected value using jquery and send it to woocommerce ajax functionality

```
function woocommerce_add_gift_box() {
    if (is_checkout()) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {            
            $('#selectedfield').click(function(){
                jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
            });

        });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Ajax will return a post data value

```
if ( ! $_POST || ( is_admin() && ! is_ajax() ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['post_data'] ) ) {
        parse_str( $_POST['post_data'], $post_data );
    } else {
        $post_data = $_POST; // fallback for final checkout (non-ajax)
    }

    $varField = $post_data['selectedfield'];
```

You can use this to tinker with your shipping methods. Using if conditions.

Hope this helps.